# Misleading stack trace involving JavaFX and generics

Tags: java, generics, javafx, javafx-8

I've encountered the following error when opening a ComboBox with prompt type and a StringConverter attached using Java 1.8u40. This was traced back to example strings left by the team doing the FXML, conflicting with a generically typed ComboBox in the Controller. We fixed this by ensuring the dummy list is replaced with items of the correct type in the initialize().

However whilst I understand the problem and how to solve it, I cannot understand the stack trace... The error occurs on at `Controller$1.toString(Controller.java:1)`

- Why is this reported at line 1, Controller itself is not generic, only its fields...?
- Is there some compiler generated magic involved?
- How could the FXML building process build a ComboBox of the correct type as generics only exist at compile type?

Original error

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
    at Controller$1.toString(Controller.java:1)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ComboBoxListViewSkin.updateDisplayText(ComboBoxListViewSkin.java:388)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ComboBoxListViewSkin.access$100(ComboBoxListViewSkin.java:57)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ComboBoxListViewSkin$2$1.updateItem(ComboBoxListViewSkin.java:425)
    at javafx.scene.control.ListCell.updateItem(ListCell.java:471)
    at javafx.scene.control.ListCell.indexChanged(ListCell.java:330)
    at javafx.scene.control.IndexedCell.updateIndex(IndexedCell.java:116)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.setCellIndex(VirtualFlow.java:1957)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.getCell(VirtualFlow.java:1797)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.getCellBreadth(VirtualFlow.java:1888)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.getMaxCellWidth(VirtualFlow.java:2508)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualContainerBase.getMaxCellWidth(VirtualContainerBase.java:94)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ComboBoxListViewSkin$3.computePrefWidth(ComboBoxListViewSkin.java:457)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.prefWidth(Parent.java:904)
    at javafx.scene.layout.Region.prefWidth(Region.java:1419)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ComboBoxPopupControl.sizePopup(ComboBoxPopupControl.java:199)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ComboBoxPopupControl.positionAndShowPopup(ComboBoxPopupControl.java:173)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ComboBoxPopupControl.show(ComboBoxPopupControl.java:154)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ComboBoxBaseSkin.handleControlPropertyChanged(ComboBoxBaseSkin.java:127)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ComboBoxListViewSkin.handleControlPropertyChanged(ComboBoxListViewSkin.java:159)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase.lambda$registerChangeListener$61(BehaviorSkinBase.java:197)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.MultiplePropertyChangeListenerHandler$1.changed(MultiplePropertyChangeListenerHandler.java:55)
    at javafx.beans.value.WeakChangeListener.changed(WeakChangeListener.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper$ReadOnlyPropertyImpl.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper.java:178)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper$ReadOnlyPropertyImpl.access$100(ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper.java:148)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper.java:144)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:110)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:144)
    at javafx.scene.control.ComboBoxBase.setShowing(ComboBoxBase.java:185)
    at javafx.scene.control.ComboBoxBase.show(ComboBoxBase.java:391)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ComboBoxBaseBehavior.show(ComboBoxBaseBehavior.java:242)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ComboBoxBaseBehavior.mouseReleased(ComboBoxBaseBehavior.java:197)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:350)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:275)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$351(GlassViewEventHandler.java:385)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:384)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
```

### Small example

I've used Integer to represent some other business specific type, too complex to paste here, the list of values is actually dynamic and loaded from a database

FXML

```
<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="205.0" prefWidth="168.0" styleClass="layout" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="Controller">
  <children>
    <ComboBox fx:id="combo" prefWidth="200" promptText="...">
      <items>
        <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
          <String fx:value="Foo" />
          <String fx:value="Bar" />
          <String fx:value="Baz" />
        </FXCollections>
      </items>
    </ComboBox>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Controller

```
public class Controller implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private ComboBox<Integer> combo;
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        combo.setConverter(new StringConverter<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public String toString(Integer object) {
                return "custom " + object.intValue();
            }
            @Override
            public Integer fromString(String string) {
                return null;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Main

```
public class ComboBoxTypeMismatch extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        try {
            stage.setScene(new Scene(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/test.fxml"))));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your StringConverter doesn't make any sense to me. What do you want to achieve here?

Comment: It's just a self contained example which has a StringConverter, the details of which are unimportant. The real application is tens of thousands of lines with custom types...

Comment: Why will you attach a StringConverter to a ComboBox whose values are already String ?

Comment: The string values, were examples left by a team doing FXML design only as prototypes... The actual developers wanted to use the correct types, which are dynamic from a database, not static. The point of the question is understanding the stack trace "line 1" and generics...

Comment: I am not very sure of your project structure, but when I try to replicate the same problem, I get an exception `Controller$1.toString(Controller.java:20)` and not at `line 1`

Comment: Now that is interesting, under some circumstances the error is reported correctly... I've seen this error when running in Eclipse Luna, SR1, on both 8u40, 8u60 on both OS X and Windows XP... What's your environment?

Comment: I was just gonna add the comment about eclipse but I see you have already found the issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a compiler issue, specifically the internal compiler used in Eclipse, Luna SR1.

If the same example is compiled using the JDK compiler the error is reported correctly at line 14

```
javac Controller.java
javac ComboBoxTypeMismatch.java
java -cp . ComboBoxTypeMismatch

Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
    at Controller$1.toString(Controller.java:14)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ComboBoxListViewSkin.updateDisplayText(ComboBoxListViewSkin.java:388)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ComboBoxListViewSkin.access$100(ComboBoxListViewSkin.java:57)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ComboBoxListViewSkin$2$1.updateItem(ComboBoxListViewSkin.java:425)
    at javafx.scene.control.ListCell.updateItem(ListCell.java:471)
```

Answer (score 3):

*Although this answer isn't a solution to OP's original question, I am still leaving this for someone who comes around with the same stacktrace and doesn't know what went wrong.*

---

You are declaring a `ComboBox<Integer>` in your controller, where as you are passing String values to it in the FXML and therefore the exception.

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

If you want to have a ComboBox which contains Integer value, then you need to pass Integer values to your ComboBox.

```
 <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
     <Integer fx:value="1" />
     <Integer fx:value="2" />
     <Integer fx:value="3" />
 </FXCollections>
```

Comment: Thanks. You're right,  will be useful for future,  as can't find this stacktrace anywhere else on the web

Answer (score 1):

> Is there some compiler generated magic involved?

Indeed, and there is why:

Normally, one should have one class per file. It means that every *.java* file produces a *.class* file after beeing compiled.

Now your file *Controller.java* contains at least 2 classes: `Controller` and an anonymous class: `new StringConverter<Integer>() {...};`. So, when Controller.java got compiled, the output **must** be stored in 2 files.

The convention taken by the java compiler to name the second file is: *EnclosingClass$n.class* where *n* is the n-th anonymous class in the enclosing class.

If you go in your *bin* directory you will see both files, *Controller.class* and *Controller$1.class* (and maybe more).

> Why is this reported at line 1, Controller itself is not generic, only
>   its fields...?

As you said, it seems a specific compiler version issue.

> How could the FXML building process build a ComboBox of the correct
>   type as generics only exist at compile type?

Where are generics involved ? In your code you declared `ComboBox<Integer>`.